# Html dynamically repeated border-image

Tags: html, css, image, border

I have a table which border I want to have a sort of zig-zag shape. I want the table to have an automatic size; resizing depending on how big the browser is. But rrathe than just having an image that gets stretched I want a seamless image that gets repeat instead.
I found out this can be done with [CSS3's Border-image](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) but by looking and [Browser Statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) I can see than only about half of all the viewers will be able to see it since no version of IE does yet support it.
So I'm looking for an alternate method. What would be the best way of doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way, I thought of having a div for each side of the table, with a repeated background image. Haven't tried it out yet but I'll do right away.
There's one problem with that though. After the number of iterations of the image has been decided by the browser, I'd prefer if either the whole row/column or only the last image to be stretched to match the image used for the corner.

Answer (score 1):

How about making it a background repeatable image instead? Will the table be resizable horizontally or vertically?